# C - Does freeing an array of pointers also free what they're pointing to?

Tags: c, free

Say I have an array of pointers to structs that contain a string each and so for something like this:

```
printf("%s\n", array[0]);
```

The output is:

```
Hello.
```

If I perform a `free(array)` will this free what `array[0]` is pointing to? (`"Hello."`).

I've spent hours attempting to manually free each element and all I get is crashes. I'm hoping this is a shortcut :/

Comment: The answer is no. You need to `free` what you `malloc`.

Comment: Does `calloc` play a role in the crashing? I haven't used `malloc`, only `calloc`.

Comment: As for your crashes, first run in a debugger to catch them, and try to learn where they happen in your code, then try to figure out *why* they happen. And if you still can't figure it out, then come back here to SO and ask a (new) question about it (and including a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which includes pointing out where the crash happens).

Comment: `calloc` is just `malloc` with an extra `memset`.

Comment: Is you can free the array like that, `array` is **not** an array, but a pointer!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This all depends on how the array was allocated. I'll give examples:

Example 1:

```
char array[10];
free(array);     // nope!
```

Example 2:

```
char *array;
array= malloc(10);   // request heap for memory
free(array);         // return to heap when no longer needed
```

Example 3:

```
char **array;
array= malloc(10*sizeof(char *));
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    array[i]= malloc(10);
}
free(array);        // nope. You should do:

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    free(array[i]);
}
free(array);
```

Ad. Example 1: `array` is allocated on the stack ("automatic variable") and cannot be released by `free`. Its stack space will be released when the function returns.

Ad. Example 2: you request storage from the heap using `malloc`. When no longer needed, return it to the heap using `free`.

Ad. Example 3: you declare an array of pointers to characters. You first allocate storage for the array, then you allocate storage for each array element to place strings in. When no longer needed, you must first release the strings (with `free`) and then release the array itself (with `free`).

Answer (score 4):

> If I perform a free(array) will this free what array[0] is pointing
>   to? ("Hello.").

No they don't get freed automatically, but depending on how you allocated each of them, there might be no need to free them actually. You would only need to free them if they point to memory which was returned by `malloc` and similar allocation functions.

Say you have array of pointers to string `array`

```
char * array[2];
array[0] = "Some text"; // You would not need to free this
array[1] = malloc(LENGTH); // This one you would have to free
```

Note in this case you don't need to free the `array` itself. Only the element with index 1.

Comment: In what case would I be able to skip freeing them?

Comment: @Laefica Ofcourse not . You will need to `free` what you have allocated .

Answer (score 2):

You only ever need to free what you manually `malloc()`. So no, depending on the pointer it might not, and might not even be necessary.